# CodeBlocks doesn't let me create a project with multiple code files

Tags: c++, file, codeblocks

I am very new to coding, so forgive me if my question is too stupid.

I just started learning how to code in C++ and now I am trying to learn how to create projects with multiple files but there's a problem. When I create a new file, I can't add more files to that project in the left panel in CodeBlocks.

Also when creating the file, CodeBlocks doesn't let me tick the option "Add file to active procejts In build target(s):". I am thinking maybe this causes the problem?

```
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is: " << add(3, 4) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Above is my main file, I want this code to call the below function which should be in the separate file, but it doesn't work.

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Thanks very much in advance for all the help!

Comment: As I remember, CodeBlocks has options to treat each file as individual project (might be useful in tutorials). Check how you create your project.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, you should choose project instead of file.

BTW, I don't recommend using Code::Blocks because of the many disadvantages of it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it now. The course that I'm following instructs that I choose "create new file", that's why I went that way, but maybe creating a new project will solve the issue.

I am using CodeBlocks as it looks easier, but I can switch later as I get more experience. 

Regards!

Comment: I just tried it and the problem is solved, the code works just fine now. Didn't think it'd be that easy. Thanks again!!!